# Ext JS Component - When can I manipulate the DOM?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to reuse some code to initialize a component back to its initial state. So i have a `reset()` function that calls an `update()` function with default parameters.

Everywhere I try, trying to access the DOM elements results in null - and its not the code as I've tested it via button event after the page has rendered. It seems using initComponent() is too early, so I've looked at subscribing to events.

Looking at the events of `Ext.Component`, the only one that seems suitable is the `render` event: "Fires after the component markup is rendered."

Again, I get a null reference. I'm not keen on using this as I dont really want to use render just in case it gets re-rendered elsewhere, its just a one time event (on/after init), but that can be called again.

When/how are we supposed to get access to the component's DOM on initialization?

Here's the class:

```
Ext.define('PegfileApp.view.ContentHeader', {
  extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.contentHeader',
  id: 'contentHeader',
  // layout

  border: 1,
  html: " \
    <h1 id='survey-header' class='lg'>Blah blah</h1> \
    <h2 id='survey-subheader' class='mb'></h2> \
    <div id='survey-header-content'></div> \
    ",
  width: 634,
  height: 75,
  listeners: 
  {
    'render': function () {
      alert("rendered");
      this.reset();
    }
  },
  // funcs

//  initComponent: function () {
////    this.on("afterrender", function () {
////      alert("rendered");
////      this.reset();
////    });
//    
//  },

  reset: function () {
    this.update('This is the header', 'This is the sub-header', 'Total number of files created: <b>30</b>')
  },

  update: function (header, subheader, content) {
    Ext.get('survey-header').update(header); // << == null
    Ext.get('survey-subheader').update(subheader);
    Ext.get('survey-header-content').update(content);
  }
});
```

Comment: Try to use `afterrender` event.

Comment: .bah you know what thats it - i had used this, but when id been testing id got my listeners in the wrong place so code wasn'y working anyway!